# Pressing back button (backBarButtonItem) in KIF?

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, kif

Does KIF provide any special support for tapping back buttons or will I have to do something like this?

```
// in parent ViewController

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel     = @"Back";

// in test class

[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel: @"Back"]];
```

The latter would be a bit unfortunate, because my code currently does not have back buttons at all and `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is and can normally remain `nil` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933280/why-is-self-navigationitem-backbarbuttonitem-always-nil)): the description in the storyboard suffices so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the back button will be labeled "Back" and accessible to VoiceOver as such as well so:

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel: @"Back"];
```

will work if you haven't done anything else.

So assuming I understand the structure of your view controllers (which is navigation, but with no explicit [`backBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem) set), then what you have should work without the parent view controller changes you're worried about.

Comment: Worked for me, perfect.

Comment: This broke in iOS 11 which now sets the accessibility label of the Back button to the title of the previous view controller on the navigation stack

Comment: It works until you erase text of the back button