# [ios]change title of back button on navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

So I want to change the text on the back button of a UIViewController, and I want it to satisfy the following criteria:

1. Text can be changed dynamically, after the view is presented.
2. Right swipe gesture from left edge of screen still works.

So far the answer I found is either
[How do I change the title of the "back" button on a Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339)
which is unable to change the text dynamically

or this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/498089/2925345
which removes the swipe gesture.

Is there any way to satisfy both of the criterias?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar is unable to change text dynamically?

Comment: no, once the view is presented, I tried to do `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.text = @"smth else";` does not work, it works before the view is presented

Comment: what prevents you from recreation of the entire barbutton with different text again?

Comment: the swipe gesture doesn't work then

Comment: Screen Edge Swipe Gesture doesn't work when we present view over the other view it works only when a view push to other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by assigning a delegate to UINavigation Controller's `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`.
And it must be executed in or after `viewWillAppear`, in this particular order

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Once I did that I can change the title of `backBarButtonItem` however I want.

Got my answer from

> http://blog.csdn.net/zhaoxy_thu/article/details/15811189

I don't know how it works, I don't know why simply assigning a delegate to a swipe gesture recognizer enables the title of back button to be customizable, I simply followed the instructions in this magical blog post. Thanks [zhaoxy_thu](http://blog.csdn.net/zhaoxy_thu) for making this work.

Answer (score 1):

If not overridden, left button in navigation bar is constructed from `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` of previous view controller. To change the text, you need to do something like

```
NSInteger count = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
if (count >= 2) {
    UIViewController* previousVC = self.navigationController.viewControllers[count-2];
    previousVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.text = @"new text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NewTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                target:nil
                                action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```