# UINavigationItem BackButton shows the same as the UINavigationItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my UINavigationController I push three of UITableViewController. In my second UITableViewController I set in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "controller2"
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "c2"
```

Then I do the following. Starting at UITableViewController one push UITableViewController two and push UITableViewController three on the UINavigationController. When I reach UITableViewController three the back button displays `controller2` instead of `c2`.

I did the same setup on the first UITableViewController and when I reach UITableViewController two the back button shows the correct title.

**Why does the back button shows the wrong title?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277838/2147250) -

> The title of the back button is either:
>
> 1. The title of the previous view controller
> 2. The name of the previous view controller's navigation item back button
>
> If you are setting the back button for the current view controller's navigation item you are
> not setting the button that get's displayed in the current view. You
> are in fact setting the back button that will be used if you push
> another view controller from it.

Or
You could init a new back button with title. Put this in the `viewDidLoad()` of view controller.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "c2", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
```