# How to change the title of the "back" bar button item?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, backbarbuttonitem

I want to change the "Root View Controller" back button to "Back" without changing the title of the Root View Controller.

I have tried these 3 code but all of them do not work.

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
```

May I know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code of the whole method for your reference:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if activePlace == -1
    {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else
    {
       // print( "String(myvar3.dynamicType) -> \(places[activePlace]["lat"].dynamicType)")
        let latitude = Double(places[activePlace]["lat"]!)
        let longitude = Double(places[activePlace]["lon"]!)

        //creating map region and annotation
        createMapRegionAndAnnotation(latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

        print(latitude)
    }
```

Comment: Set the title of the previous UIViewController to the one you want.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497974/changing-the-uibackbuttonitem-title

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to override previous screen segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "My title"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
}
```

Comment: Hi may I know why does this not work?`navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title  = "Button"` Thank you for your help

Comment: @TeeMingWei If you are setting the back button for the current view controller's navigation item you are not setting the button that get's displayed in the current view. You are in fact setting the back button that will be used if you push another view controller from it.

Comment: 1)doesn't work at all; 2)overriding `prepareForSegue` without of calling `super.prepareForSegue` is incorrect

Answer (score 5):

You can also change it from storyboard by changing the back button property in the navigation item of the previous view controller as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried it out and it works too

Answer (score 1):

In child view this worked for me;

`self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Back"`

Comment: it overwrites the title of the previous screen

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = ""
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```